# Sorting data by color coded cells

Tags: excel

I have a table of data that I use to analyze some basic data that I use empty cells with a certain color fill to use as organization tabs for easy identification of different categories. I was wondering if there was anyway to use the data filter option to sort by these specific categories.

My table looks something like this:

```
| Category |   Date  |  Type | Value |
|:--------:|:-------:|:-----:|:-----:|
| COLOR1   | 1/1/12  | TYPE1 | 203   |
| COLOR2   | 1/3/12  | TYPE1 | 205   |
| COLOR3   | 1/4/12  | TYPE2 | 195   |
| COLOR2   | 1/7/12  | TYPE1 | 641   |
| COLOR2   | 1/7/12  | TYPE2 | 52    |
| COLOR1   | 1/11/12 | TYPE3 | 901   |
```

except reimagine the Category column to have actual colors and no text.

Also, if it helps, I have a legend in the worksheet looks like this:

```
|    Category Legend    |
|:--------:|:----------:|
| COLOR1   | Category 1 |
| COLOR2   | Category 2 |
| COLOR3   | Category 3 |
```

Another thing that might help is if its possible to use color value somehow in an "if statement". I might then be able to assign data to automatically populate other tables based on when I assign a color to that Category column. Or if I could assign the text "Category 1" to any column that I added COLOR1 too and change the text of Category 1 to "COLOR1" as well.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot actually put a value into the cell, use a custom number format of `;;;` and then add conditional formatting to color the cells? It is generally easier to type a number into a cell than manually applying color fill.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of that.... Now I'm adding the text "Category 1" to the column and creating formatting rules to change the cell fill and text color both to COLOR1. Now I can sort using the Category names. Thank you for helping me see through my stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Filter by Color' to filter by your categories. To sort use 'Sort by Color' in the filter dropdown, this will place the selected color at the top of your list, use this for each of your colours and it will stack them together in the order selected (most recent being on top).

[image]